# Docker Mac - error running ls on large directory

Tags: macos, docker, ls

I have a docker Mac host running an Ubuntu 19.10 guest. I am sharing a folder on my Mac filesystem that contains ~56,000 files totaling 230MB. When I `ls` that directory from within a docker container, it responds with:

```
Input/output error: <the directory name>
```

The folder is shared when I run the container via `docker run -v /path/on/mac/fs:/path/in/guest -it my-image:latest /bin/bash`.

- When I `ls` the directory from a Mac shell, it works as expected.
- Trying with a pared-down version of the directory (29k files) works as expected.

I have found a workaround: disabling "Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing" in the docker dashboard. `ls` works from within the container, but I still don't really understand the root of the problem.

56k files is not trivial, but also I wouldn't have guessed it's *so* big as to break docker.

So my questions:

1. Why might this be happening? Is this actually a gRPC issue, or something else?
2. Is there any documentation on gRPC FUSE limits? I couldn't find any.